# Using ngModel inside generic component

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a Generic component that is a list of Titles and Values. To make this Generic, I pass in an object which contains 2 mapping functions, one of these functions is read and another write.

This is the read mapping function.

```
read: ((s: ValidDto) => idx(s, _ => this._datePipe.transform(new Date(_.Incident.Date), 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm'))),
```

This is the write mapping function.

```
write: (s: ValidDto, val: Date) => s.Incident.Date = val
```

So each property that I pass in will have on of these which point to a different property inside the data object from the API.

In the component itself, the idea is that if we are in an editable state, that we want to update the data object from the API.

I currently have this code in the HTML:

```
<input *ngIf="edit" type="text" [ngModel]="item2.read(data)" (ngModelChange)="item2.write(data, $event)" />
```

I have tried using *[(ngModel)]* but this does not accept a mapping function.

How else can i achieve this?

Comment: can you demonstrate this in stackblitz.com please?

Comment: I appreciate what you are trying to do here but the Angular way of accomplishing [dynamically generated](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) forms is to use [reactive-forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms). This is still possible though, let me write it up.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this to be working:

```
constructor() {
  interval(5000).subscribe(_ => this.dto =  { value: 10 });
}

dto = { value: 5 };
item2 = this.createWrapper(dto => dto.value.toString(), (dto, val) => dto.value = val);

public createWrapper(readFn, writeFn) {
  return {
    read: (dto) => readFn(dto),
    write: (dto, x) => writeFn(dto, x),
  };
}
```

View:

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="item2.read(dto)" (ngModelChange)="item2.write(dto, $event)" />
<br />
{{ dto.value  }}
```

I've used an interval to simulate receiving data from the API, everything works fine.